# How to convert a cross tab sheet into a table in excel without using macros?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cross tab and I want to automatically turn it into a table, how can I go about doing this. Note i'm happy to use excel formulas or power query (I think it used be called M) but do not want VBA scripts. Also if I add a new value or remove a value I should be able to refresh the output table.

e.g.

**Cross Tab**

|  | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | X |  |  |
| Row 2 |  | X |  |
| Row 3 | D |  | Y |

**Transformed output**

| Column Name | Row Name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column 1 | Row 1 | X |
| Column 1 | Row 3 | D |
| Column 2 | Row 2 | X |
| Column 3 | Row 3 | Y |

The reason I want to do this I have a case where it's easier to capture the data into the cross tab, but better for analysis in the table format.  Additionally the data capture and analysis don't occur in sequence so I want to simplify updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using ***Unpivot Columns*** in Excel's **Power Query**.

1. Select the data range
2. Right-click and choose ***Get Data from Table/Range...***, and make sure the *My table has headers* checkbox is ticked (which will open the ***Power Query Editor*** with your data/range)
3. Select the data columns (Select *Column 1* and then Shift-select *Column 3*)
4. Under **Transform** press ***Unpivot Columns***
5. After ensuring it looks like you want, click ***Load & Save*** and see the newly created table in the new Sheet

You can then refresh the table data - after adding to the initial sheet - by pressing ***Refresh*** in the Query tab (or/and you can set it to periodically automatically update.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways you can approach this,  some slicker (but more difficult to understand) than others. Here's an old school one.

If you have *C* columns and *R* rows in the body of your cross-tab the first step is to generate a list of all possible column/row combinations. The starting point is column 1 and row 1 which is written in shorthand as (1,1). Put these two values in say cells `A2` and `B2`, with cells `A1:C1` having labels "Column", "Row" and "Value", respectively.

In `B3` put the formula
`=IF(B2=R,1,B2+1)`
using either a hardcoded value of *R* (eg 5 if you have 5 rows) or as an absolute cell reference (ie using $ signs) containing *R* if that is what you prefer.

In `A3` put the formula
`=IF(B3=1,1+A2,A2)`.

Copy the range `A3:B3` downwards until you have the final pair with values *C* and *R* at the end of  your list in columns `A` and `B`, respectively.

You should now have a list with *C*×*R* rows containing all the possible column/row combinations. The list starts with (1,1), (1,2) down to (1,*R*), followed by (2,1), (2,2),...(2,*R*) ... and finishing (*C*,1), (*C*,2),...,(*C*,*R*)

The next step is to extract the values from the body of your cross-tab. This is slightly complicated by the fact that not every cell in your cross-tab is populated.

Using the name `CrossTab` to represent the range of the body of your cross-tab, put the formula

`=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(CrossTab,B2,A2)), NA(), INDEX(CrossTab,B2,A2))`

in cell `C2` and copy downwards to the end of the list in columns `A` and `B`.

If you prefer not to name the range as `CrossTab` you can instead use an absolute cell reference range of the body of the cross-tab eg `$G$2:$I$6` in place of `CrossTab` in the formula above.

You now have all the data from the cross-tab in the required list format but with any empty cells in the cross-tab represented by the `#N/A` error value.

The final step is to use Excel's list filtering facilities (access via the ribbon's Data option) to filter out the unwanted `#N/A`'s and then simply copy and past the filtered list to a convenient location in your work book. The pasted values will be values rather than formulas in all 3 columns.

As I note  above, there are quite a few different ways to achieve your task but this is quite a straightforward and simple one to follow.

[image: Transforming cross-tab to list]

Something which is much less straightforward to follow but a bit slicker is this:

```
=LET(
    ct, G2:I6,
    r, ROWS(ct),
    c, COLUMNS(ct),
    lis, SEQUENCE(r * c, 1, ),
    cols, 1 + INT((lis - 1) / r),
    rows, 1 + MOD(lis - 1, r),
    allvals, INDEX(ct, rows, cols),
    allna, IF(
        ISBLANK(allvals),
        NA(),
        allvals
    ),
    keep, NOT(ISNA(allna)),
    FILTER(
        HSTACK(cols, rows, allna),
        keep
    )
)
```

It use dynamic arrays and requires Excel 2021 or 365, but, in essence, follows a fairly similar approach to the simpler solution given initially.

The body of the cross-tab is in range `G2:I6` as in the screenshot above and is assigned to variable *ct* in the `LET()` function.

Also in the `LET()`  *c* and *r* are, respectively, the number of columns and rows in the cross-tab, *lis* is a column array which counts from 1 to *c*×*r* whilst *cols* and *rows* convert *lis* to the values previously found in the columns labelled "Column" and "Row", respectively, in the earlier solution.

*allvals* uses the `INDEX()` function to get a single column list of the values in the cross-tab, with *allna* inserting the `#N/A` for any unused elements of the cross-tab. *keep* is an array of booleans identifying the elements of *allna* not equal to `#N/A`.

The `HSTACK()` in the final part of the let puts the column arrays *cols*, *rows* and *allna* side-by-side into a 3 column array whilst the `FILTER()` which wraps around this filters out any row which corresponds to an unused cell in the original cross-tab.